# How to Fix Node Placement in a Family Tree Using DOT Language in Graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am trying to draw a family tree using the DOT language. I use auxiliary nodes to make the tree look neat, but in some cases, for an unknown reason, one of the nodes is placed in an illogical place at all. In the example below, the location of node J should be next to I, but as you can see, it goes to the far right of the drawing.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
digraph FamilyTree {
     edge [dir=none, penwidth=2];
    rankdir=TB;
    "A" [shape=BOX, ];
    "B" [shape=BOX,];
    "C" [shape=BOX, ];
    "D" [shape=BOX,];
    "E" [shape=BOX, ];
    "F" [shape=BOX, ];
    "c1" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c1" -> "F" [arrowhead=none];
    "G" [shape=BOX, ];
    "c2" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c2" -> "G" ;
    "H" [shape=BOX, ];
    "I" [shape=BOX, ];
    "c3" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c3" -> "I" ;
    "J" [shape=BOX, ];
    "c4" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c4" -> "J" ;
    "K" [shape=BOX,];
    "c5" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c5" -> "K" ;
    "L" [shape=BOX, ];
    "c6" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c6" -> "L" ;
    "M" [shape=BOX, ];
    "c7" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c7" -> "M" ;
    "Couple_5780_1" [shape=point, color=gray,  label=""];
    "Couple_5355_1" [shape=point, color=gray,  label=""];
    "Couple_8222_1" [shape=point, color=gray, label=""];
    "Couple_8222_2" [shape=point, color=gray,  label=""];
    "Couple_8222_3" [shape=point, color=gray, label=""];
    { rank=same; "A" -> "Couple_5780_1" -> "B"  }
    { rank=same; "C" -> "Couple_5355_1" -> "D" }
    { rank=same;"E"->"Couple_8222_1"->"F"->"Couple_8222_2"->"G"->"Couple_8222_3"->"H"}
    
    "c3" -> "c4" [arrowhead=none,constraint=false];
    
    { rank=same; "c3"; "c4"; }
    "c6" -> "c7" [arrowhead=none,constraint=false];
    { rank=same; "c6"; "c7"; }
    "Couple_5780_1" -> "c1" ;
    "Couple_5355_1" -> "c2";
    "Couple_8222_1" -> "c3" ;
    "Couple_8222_2" -> "c5";
    "Couple_8222_3" -> "c6" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Graphviz algorithms are complex and sometimes wacky.
Being unable to get **dot** to keep a desired node sequence is a known issue (https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/1569) with no guaranteed solution, but below is your desired result.
It adds groups (https://www.graphviz.org/docs/attrs/group/) to (try to) force vertical alignment and adds "J" and "c4" to one of the groups to coerce the desired position.

```
digraph FamilyTree {


    edge [dir=none, penwidth=2];
    rankdir=TB;
    "A" [shape=BOX, ];
    "B" [shape=BOX,];
    "C" [shape=BOX, ];
    "D" [shape=BOX,];
    "E" [shape=BOX, ];
    "F" [shape=BOX, group=F1];
    "c1" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01 group=F1 ];
    "c1" -> "F" [arrowhead=none];
    "G" [shape=BOX, group=G1];
    "c2" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01 group=G1];
    "c2" -> "G" ;
    "H" [shape=BOX, ];
    "I" [shape=BOX, group=I1];
    "c3" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01 group=I1];
    "c3" -> "I" ;
    "J" [shape=BOX, group=F1];
    "c4" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01 group=F1];
    "c4" -> "J" ;
    "K" [shape=BOX,];
    "c5" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c5" -> "K" ;
    "L" [shape=BOX, ];
    "c6" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c6" -> "L" ;
    "M" [shape=BOX, ];
    "c7" [shape=point, label="",width=0.01, height=0.01];
    "c7" -> "M" ;
    "Couple_5780_1" [shape=point, color=gray,  label="" group=F1];
    "Couple_5355_1" [shape=point, color=gray,  label="" group=G1];
    "Couple_8222_1" [shape=point, color=gray, label="" group=I1];
    "Couple_8222_2" [shape=point, color=gray,  label=""];
    "Couple_8222_3" [shape=point, color=gray, label=""];
    { rank=same; "A" -> "Couple_5780_1" -> "B"  }
    { rank=same; "C" -> "Couple_5355_1" -> "D" }
    { rank=same;"E"->"Couple_8222_1"->"F"->"Couple_8222_2"->"G"->"Couple_8222_3"->"H"}

    "c3" -> "c4" [arrowhead=none, constraint=false]
    
    { rank=same; "c3"; "c4"; }
    "c6" -> "c7" [arrowhead=none,constraint=false];
    { rank=same; "c6"; "c7"; }
    "Couple_5780_1" -> "c1" ;
    "Couple_5355_1" -> "c2";
    "Couple_8222_1" -> "c3" ;
    "Couple_8222_2" -> "c5";
    "Couple_8222_3" -> "c6" ;

F->c4 [style=invis]  //  for F1 group

}
```

Giving:
[image]